# Simple JISON parser to detect paragraphs

Tags: parsing, jison

For GOD SAKE!! How to write a simple jison grammar that recognizes a document with paragraphs??? I'm using the following grammar:

```
%lex
%%
(\r?\n)+\s*                 return 'NL'
[^\S\r\n]+                  return 'SPACE'
.                           return 'CHAR'
<<EOF>>                     return 'NL'
/lex

%s document

%%
document    : paragraphs                { console.log($1); return $1; }
            ;

paragraphs : paragraph                  { $$ = [$1] }
           | paragraphs paragraph       { $$ = $1.concat($2) }
           ;

paragraph  : NL
           | text NL                    { $$ = $1 }
           ;

text        : string                    { $$ = [$1] }
            | text SPACE string         { $$ = $1.concat($3) }
            ;

string      : CHAR
            | string CHAR               { $$ = $1 + $2 }
            ;
```

And for test i'm using:

```
Hello world
Monkey beast
Hi
```

What i want as you can see by my grammar is that a paragraph became array of words.

Trying this out in the JISON website it keep me giving:

```
[["Hello","world"],"Monkey","beast","Hi"]
```

while what i do expect is

```
[["Hello","world"],["Monkey","beast"],["Hi"]]
```

Could anyone help me????

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind!! The problem was with me, but for future reference: just replace:

```
| paragraphs paragraph       { $$ = $1.concat($2) }
```

by

```
| paragraphs paragraph       { $$ = $1.concat([$2]) }
```

:)

Cheers!